# How I can write this code to work in oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

How I can write this code ( Sql Server) to work in Oracle PL/SQl ?

```
  DECLARE @ID INTEGER

  SELECT @ID = ISNULL(MAX(EmployeeID),0) + 1

  FROM EmployeeTable
```

Comment: You should probably be using an `IDENTITY` for this purpose (an autoincrementing number?) in SQL Server, and a `SEQUENCE` in Oracle. Look those things up and understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the equivalent code for oracle

```
declare
    id number;
    begin
    select nvl(max(employeeid),0)+1 into id from employeetable;
    dbms_output.put_line(id);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE ID INTEGER;

BEGIN
SELECT
    NVL(MAX(EmployeeID),0) + 1 INTO ID
FROM
    EmployeeTable
END;
/
```